# How to use nested loops for a p5.js pyramid?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested, processing, p5.js

I am very new to javascript and I am confused by nested loops I managed to get my desired out come but I know there has to be a more simplified version. Or more likely just a better version.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
}
function draw() {
  background(200);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    square(i * 50, i * 50, 50);
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      square(i * 50 - 50, i * 50, 50);
      for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        square(i * 50 - 100, i * 50, 50);
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
          square(i * 50 - 150, i * 50, 50);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just 2 nested loop. The outer one is for the rows an runs from 0 to the number of rows. The inner one is for the columns ad runs from 0 to the number (index) of the current row.

Int the following example `no_of_rows` specifies the number of rows and can be set to any value:

```js
let no_of_rows = 3;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 600);
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  
    // for each row
    for (let row = 0; row <= no_of_rows; row++) {
      
        // for each column in the row
        for (let column = 0; column <= row ; column ++) {
           square(column * 50, row * 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see I was looking at them like individuals not as rows and columns. Thanks!